# Add proper selector for keybinding event in Atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

I develop a package, which allows user to use <kbd>Home</kbd> button to toggle cursor position in **soft-wrapped lines**, as it is in *Komodo Edit* editor.

In my `toggle()` function I try to get active text editor from Atom Workspace using [`getActiveTextEditor`](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.23.1/Workspace#instance-getActiveTextEditor) function and then I do my logic.

```
atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()
```

I bind a <kbd>Home</kbd> key with a selector `atom-text-editor.editor`, and it mainly works fine until triggered inside *Search&Replace* pane or *Command Palette*.

```
"atom-text-editor.editor": {
  "home": "toggle-home:toggle"
}
```

In this case, `getActiveTextEditor` returns always a currently edited file's text editor. It leads to a situation, when a cursor is moved inside an edited file's pane, but not inside focused field. When I use a <kbd>Home</kbd> inside a text field in *Settings* pane, Atom throws an exception, as it can't find any active text editor.

I did a research through Atom Docs, Atom API, even community packages, but all I found, was adding *'mini'* to my event selector, to narrow event scope a bit.

```
"atom-text-editor.editor:not([mini])": {
  "home": "toggle-home:toggle"
}
```

Nevertheless it still causes exception or misbehaviour in text fields without *'mini'* (ie. textarea of Git/GitHub package).

**What I want to achieve is:**
1) to find a proper keybinding selector, that would fire only inside currently edited file pane;
OR
2) to find a method to get focused  instance (Search&Replace, Command Palette or any other field) for further processing.

**Solution**

As DamnedScholar mentioned [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/add-proper-selector-for-keybinding-event-in-atom-editor/51512/8?u=qbadev):

> the selector `atom-workspace-axis.vertical atom-pane-container atom-text-editor:not([mini])` will do it.

Already tested, works fine.